# Functional testing in Symfony2 gives me error: Failed asserting that false is true

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I have action where I do this:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('url_key'));
```

In my test I do this:

```
$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());
```

But I get error:

> Failed asserting that false is true

Where is my problem? Why I am getting error?

My full test:

```
public function testDeleteAction()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('GET', '/translation/delete/messages/test.key');
    $client->followRedirects();
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());
}
```

Comment: Did you enabled [`followRedirects()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#redirecting)? I had the same problem than you and was unable to detect the redirection (Symfony 2.6).

Comment: @A.L, I am use 2.6 too. I enable followRedirects() but still have same error. I will add my full `testAction`  to question, maybe you can explain what exactly I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `followRedirect` only if you want perform another request after getting redirect response. You don't need it in your case (and even you must not use it - if you do `followRedirects` then you'll get another response which is not "redirect response" anymore - so assertion will fail).

Probably something went wrong with the first request. Check what is the status and optionally the content of the response:

```
public function testDeleteAction()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('GET', '/translation/delete/messages/test.key');
    // of course you should use the "pro-way" and check it with debbuger instead of var_dumps ;)
    var_dump($client->getResponse()->getStatus());
    var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());
}
```

Check if there is no 404 or 500 status - and if so, then find out why (or extend your question with additional info).

Comment: I suggested `followRedirects()` in a comment to the question but I didn't knew I was wrong, the documentation is not clear with its use. Thanks.

Comment: I just tested and the test `$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());` only works if `followRedirects()` is not used. (or you can use ` $client->followRedirects(false);` to disable it if needed).

Comment: thanks. I getting 500 error code... first I found that I use broken url. Proper Url is `/translation/delete/en/messages/test.key`. But it didn help...

Comment: Ok, so what's the status and response's content right now?